# 'block in draw' rails 6 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to split my routes into different files after moving to rails 6, I've checked the docs and done the following:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'summary#index'

  draw(:general)
end
```

in the `api_schema_controller we have

```rb
module Api
  module V1
    class ApiSchemaController < ApplicationController
      CONTROLLER_NAMES = %w(SalesOrders VatRates VatTypes Companies ExchangeRates Auth Products BankAccounts Locations Customers
             SalesInvoices Receipts Accounts BudgetModels)

      require_relative '../../../../lib/internal_api/open_api_builder'

      def self.build_route_for_action(routing_object, controller_name, controller_class, action_name, action_conf)
        path = ApiSchemaController.action_path(controller_class, action_conf, true)
        verb = action_conf[:verb].present? ? action_conf[:verb].to_s : 'get'

        routing_object.send(verb, path, action: action_name, controller: controller_name.underscore)
      end

      def self.build_routes(routing_thing)
        unless ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?
          self::CONTROLLER_NAMES.each do |controller_name|
            module_root = self.module_root
            controller_class = (module_root + '::' + controller_name + 'Controller').constantize

            controller_class::ACTIONS.each do |action_name, action_conf|
              self.build_route_for_action(routing_thing, controller_name, controller_class, action_name, action_conf.deep_dup)
            end
          end
        end
      end

      def self.module_root
        self.to_s.gsub(/::[^:]*$/, '') # not super sure about this reg ex, maybe splitting would be better
      end

      def open_api
        controller_names = self.class::CONTROLLER_NAMES
        if params[:only_controllers].present?
          only = params[:only_controllers].split(',')
          controller_names = only.select { |c| c.in?(controller_names) }
        end

        module_root = self.class.module_root
        schema_builder = OpenApiBuilder.new

        controller_names.each do |controller_name|
          schema_builder.add_paths_from_controller_class(
              (module_root + '::' + controller_name + 'Controller').constantize
          )
        end

        render json: schema_builder.to_json
        # render text: schema_builder.to_yaml, content_type: 'text/yaml'
      end

      def get_node_test_result
        dir = File.expand_path('../../../../../node', __FILE__)
        render json: `node #{dir}/index.js`
      end

      protected

      def self.action_path(controller_class, action_conf, for_route = false)
        path = '/' + controller_class.controller_name.gsub('_', '-')
        path += action_conf[:path] unless action_conf[:path].blank?
        path = path.gsub(/{(.*?)}/, ':\1') if for_route

        path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

in `config/routes/general.rb` I have the following

```rb
# api routes
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    get 'ping', action: :ping, controller: 'summary'
    get 'version', action: :version, controller: 'summary'

    delete 'sign_out', action: :sign_out, controller: 'authenticate'
    Api::V1::ApiSchemaController.build_routes(self)
  end
end
```

However, I'm getting the following when starting the server

```
Error:[rake --prereqs] /home/ben/code/BusinessCloudEssential/app/controllers/api/v1/api_schema_controller.rb:17:in `build_routes': undefined method `needs_migration?' for ActiveRecord::Migrator:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /home/ben/code/app/config/routes/general.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in draw'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:970:in `block (2 levels) in namespace'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:901:in `scope'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:970:in `block in namespace'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1886:in `path_scope'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:969:in `namespace'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1596:in `namespace'
    from /home/ben/code/BusinessCloudEssential/config/routes/general.rb:3:in `block in draw'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:970:in `block (2 levels) in namespace'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:901:in `scope'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:970:in `block in namespace'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1886:in `path_scope'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:969:in `namespace'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1596:in `namespace'
    from /home/ben/code/BusinessCloudEssential/config/routes/general.rb:2:in `draw'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1624:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1624:in `draw'
    from /home/ben/code/app/config/routes.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:427:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:427:in `eval_block'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:409:in `draw'
    from /home/ben/code/app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:47:in `block in load_paths'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:47:in `each'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:47:in `load_paths'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:21:in `reload!'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:35:in `block in updater'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:195:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:384:in `initialize!'
    from /home/ben/code/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:106:in `preload'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure what the error is as I've followed the docs but I this seems to be how the api is generating routes, not my code I'm just not sure of the best way to refactor it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error `undefined method 'needs_migration?' for ActiveRecord::Migrator:Class (NoMethodError)` be thrown because the method `needs_migration?` belongs to `ActiveRecord::MigrationContext` not `ActiveRecord::Migrator`

try this

```rb
# api_schema_controller
# ...
def self.build_routes(routing_thing)
 unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.needs_migration?
#...
```